# Before-sep spacing with titlesec at top of page

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I'm using some packages in conjunction that I think are causing problems. First, I  am using the report class. Second, I want a 1 inch margin around the page, so I use `geometry`. Third, I do not want there to be a new page when a new chapter starts, so I use a command I found on another StackOverflow post. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%Set margins to 1 inch
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

%turn off new page at new chapter
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{\par}{}{} 
\makeatother 

\usepackage[bf,compact,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1em}{}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-\topskip}{40pt}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{The First Chapter}

    Some text

    \chapter{The Second Chapter}

    More text
\end{document}
```

Essentially, I want the spacing to be 1 inch from the page edge if the chapter is at the top of the page. If the chapter is in the middle of the page, as in `The Second Chapter`, I want a smaller spacing, say `5 pt`. I tried experimenting with `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-\topskip}{40pt}` and `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}`, but this messes up the spacing of the second chapter (it not being `5 pt`). Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1 inch from the physical top of the page, i.e. at the top margin?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, that would be correct, thanks.

Comment: Copy the definition of `\@makechapterhead` from report.cls to your preamble and change the `\vspace*{50pt}` to `\vspace{5mm}`  (not the missing asterisk).